# Mysql query result date time wise

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, sql-order-by

I tried like this 
This is my Query

```
SELECT sloat_day, sloat_start_time 
FROM time_table 
WHERE sloat_day BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-07' 
ORDER BY sloat_day, sloat_start_time ASC
```

I got below output

```
sloat_day   sloat_start_time
2014-12-01  6.30
2014-12-01  7.30
2014-12-01  18.30
2014-12-01  19.30
2014-12-02  6.30
2014-12-02  7.30
2014-12-02  18.30
2014-12-02  19.30
2014-12-03  6.30
2014-12-03  7.30
2014-12-03  18.30
2014-12-03  19.30
2014-12-04  18.30
2014-12-04  19.30
2014-12-05  7.30
2014-12-05  18.30
2014-12-05  19.30
2014-12-06  19.30
2014-12-07  7.30
2014-12-07  8.30
2014-12-07  18.30
2014-12-07  19.30
```

I want query result like below what i want to change in query to got this output please help me

```
2014-12-01  6.30
2014-12-02  6.30
2014-12-03  6.30
2014-12-04  18.30
2014-12-05  7.30
2014-12-06  19.30
2014-12-07  7.30
2014-12-01  7.30
2014-12-02  7.30
2014-12-03  7.30
2014-12-04  19.30
2014-12-05  18.30
2014-12-07  8.30
2014-12-01  18.30
2014-12-02  18.30
2014-12-03  18.30
2014-12-05  19.30
2014-12-07  18.30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sloat_day, sloat_start_time
FROM (SELECT sloat_day, sloat_start_time, 
             IF(@day=@day:=sloat_day, @id:=@id+1, @id:=1) rank  
      FROM time_table, (SELECT @id:=0, @day:='') AS a 
      WHERE sloat_day BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-07' 
      ORDER BY sloat_day, sloat_start_time 
    ) AS A 
ORDER BY rank, sloat_day, sloat_start_time
```

Check [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b4032/1):

**OUTPUT**

```
|         SLOAT_DAY | SLOAT_START_TIME |
|-------------------| -----------------|
| December, 01 2014 | 06:30:00         |
| December, 02 2014 | 06:30:00         |
| December, 03 2014 | 06:30:00         |
| December, 04 2014 | 18:30:00         |
| December, 05 2014 | 07:30:00         |
| December, 06 2014 | 19:30:00         |
| December, 07 2014 | 07:30:00         |
| December, 01 2014 | 07:30:00         |
| December, 02 2014 | 07:30:00         |
| December, 03 2014 | 07:30:00         |
| December, 04 2014 | 19:30:00         |
| December, 05 2014 | 18:30:00         |
| December, 07 2014 | 08:30:00         |        
| December, 01 2014 | 18:30:00         |
| December, 02 2014 | 18:30:00         |
| December, 03 2014 | 18:30:00         |
| December, 05 2014 | 19:30:00         |
| December, 07 2014 | 18:30:00         |
| December, 01 2014 | 19:30:00         |
| December, 02 2014 | 19:30:00         |
| December, 03 2014 | 19:30:00         |
| December, 07 2014 | 19:30:00         |
```

Comment: date repetedly came so i change ORDER BY rank,  sloat_start_time,sloat_day 
after change  I got output like this date 2014-12-07 came 2 times

Comment: Thank you so much how to use join query i want to get user name in usertable with help of the id column in time_table

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of the columns in the ORDER clausule, like this.

```
SELECT sloat_day, sloat_start_time 
FROM time_table 
WHERE sloat_day BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-07' 
ORDER BY sloat_start_time, sloat_day ASC
```

This way, the query will be ordered first by sloat_start_time.

Comment: I got output like this date 2014-12-07 came 2 times its not i expect
sloat_day  sloat_start_time
2014-12-01  6.30
2014-12-02  6.30
2014-12-03  6.30
2014-12-04  6.30
2014-12-05  6.30
2014-12-06  6.30
2014-12-01  7.30
2014-12-02  7.30
2014-12-03  7.30
2014-12-04  7.30
2014-12-05  7.30
2014-12-06  7.30
2014-12-07  7.30
2014-12-07  8.30
2014-12-01  18.30
2014-12-02  18.30
2014-12-03  18.30
2014-12-04  18.30
2014-12-05  18.30
2014-12-06  18.30
2014-12-07  18.30
2014-12-01  19.30
2014-12-02  19.30
2014-12-03  19.30
2014-12-04  19.30
2014-12-05  19.30
2014-12-06  19.30
2014-12-07  19.30

Answer (score 0):

Try running this

```
SELECT sloat_day, sloat_start_time 
FROM time_table 
WHERE sloat_day BETWEEN '2014-12-01' AND '2014-12-07' 
GROUP BY sloat_day
ORDER BY sloat_start_time, sloat_day ASC
```

MySQL will run everything in the order that you ask, therefore setting it to order by `sloat_day` first will make it order by that column first.

Comment: I got output like this date 2014-12-07 came 2 times its not i expect
sloat_day  sloat_start_time
2014-12-01  6.30
2014-12-02  6.30
2014-12-03  6.30
2014-12-04  6.30
2014-12-05  6.30
2014-12-06  6.30
2014-12-01  7.30
2014-12-02  7.30
2014-12-03  7.30
2014-12-04  7.30
2014-12-05  7.30
2014-12-06  7.30
2014-12-07  7.30
2014-12-07  8.30
2014-12-01  18.30
2014-12-02  18.30
2014-12-03  18.30
2014-12-04  18.30
2014-12-05  18.30
2014-12-06  18.30
2014-12-07  18.30
2014-12-01  19.30
2014-12-02  19.30
2014-12-03  19.30
2014-12-04  19.30
2014-12-05  19.30
2014-12-06  19.30
2014-12-07  19.30